# Simple variable update and write to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems simple but its is buzzing me right now.

Here is everything explained, hope someone helps me Im gonna crazy for this simple thing.

```
<script>var pricetotal=60;</script>
<select id="product-select">
    <option>Black</option>
    <option>Lime</option>
    <option>Navy</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
</select>
    <select id="product-select2">
    <option>Black</option>
    <option>Lime</option>
    <option>Navy</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
</select>
    <!--I have multiple section forms each with different ID..
    // I want to print on page 60$, but when user selects any of the 2 option forms the price will get +5$ for each.
-->

    Total price <script>document.write(pricetotal)</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/coderised/t9AfR/1/

Comment: So you just give us markup and an empty jsfiddle? We need to see some effort here, where's the JavaScript code?

Comment: @elclanrs: In the HTML.

Comment: There isnt any JS mandatory for this, except I have some jquery which changes some image on select change.. like this  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#product-select').change(function () {
        var newimg = "imgs/" + ($('#product-select').find(":selected").text()) + ".png";
        $("#myimg").attr("src", newimg);

Comment: seems to work for me, if it's supposed to write 60 at the end there ?

Comment: I think you'll run into a problem though when craft your own solution due to `document.write`. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) for more info. It would be better to use the DOM.

Comment: yeah 60 at the beginning, but when user select for example Black from first form the page should automatically update to 65, same for other form (70).

Comment: Why on earth would it update, where's the logic for that ?

Comment: there is always an option selected unless you add a blank one.

Comment: I can add blank option if that would help to get near solution..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k2778/

Comment: @adeneo that's is thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var s = 60;
    $('select').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length) {
            s = s + 5
        }
    });
    alert(s);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/t9AfR/3/)

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what it is you are trying to do/want, but I hope that this will help you.

```
<select id="product-select">
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="Lime">Lime</option>
</select>
<select id="product-select2">
    <option value="Navy">Navy</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>

Total price <span id="price">60</span>
```

You said you are using jQuery.  With it, you can add:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var basePrice = 60, 
    $product_select = $('#product-select'), 
    $product_select2 = $('#product-select2'), 
    calcPrice = function() {
        var price = basePrice;
        switch($product_select.val()) { //Change price based on prod_select1
            case 'Black':
                price += 5;
                break;
            case 'Lime':
                price += 10;
                break;
        }
        switch($product_select2.val()) { //Change price based on prod_select2
            case 'Navy':
                price += 5;
                break;
            case 'Blue':
                price += 10;
                break;
        }
        $('#price').text(price); //Update displayed price
    };
    $product_select.on('change' calcPrice); //When changed, update price
    $product_select2.on('change', calcPrice); //When changed, update price
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can use `.val()` to get the selected value and do things based on that.

http://jsfiddle.net/coderised/t9AfR/1/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I actually answered your question but I enjoyed the excercise none the less. I set it up to dynamically populate the actual $$$ amount. I assumed you wanted to update the price based on the product combination selection. I kept it simple since I don't know your pricing rules, etc. But think this can get you going and it is a library agnostic approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/docluv/WVaRr/6/

```
var totalprice = document.querySelector(".total-price"),
pricetotal = 60,
prod1 = document.getElementById("product-select"),
prod2 = document.getElementById("product-select2");
```

function calcPrice() {

```
setText(totalprice, ++pricetotal);
```

}

function setText(e, s) {

```
if (e.innerText) {
    e.innerText = s;
} else if (e.textContent) {
    e.textContent = s;
}
```

}

setText(totalprice, pricetotal);

prod1.addEventListener("change", calcPrice, false);
prod2.addEventListener("change", calcPrice, false);